# Showing 'Using directive is unnecessary' incorrectly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I am following a tutorial: [C# | Change Windows Wallpaper Every 24 Hours From Folder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqGXymyElRI)

I am running into an issue where I am trying to use RegistryKey and the Registry class but the 'using Microsoft.Win32;' is not being used.

I have tried deleting the .vs folder in the source/repos
I did add an entry in the .csproj that allowed it to work but when I was testing something, I removed it and then trying to re-add it caused it to not work anymore.

I also noticed that at one point I had NuGet in the solution.  I'm not sure if this is important.

This is my first time using Visual Studio and C# as I previously did my programs in Java.

My current program setup looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ksoQ.jpg)

Comment: You've created a .NET Core application. I don't know what the tutorial shows (can't play it) but I expect it expected you to create a .NET Framework application instead.

Comment: Yes this was the solution! Thank you!  I did not have the option to use a Console App (.NET Framework).  After installing  the '.NET desktop development' pack the option showed up.

Comment: Btw, you don't need to access the registry to get the current wallpaper. [SystemParametersInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfow) can be used for both: Set it with  `uiAction = SETDESKWALLPAPER (0x0014)` and get it with  `GETDESKWALLPAPER (0x00073)`. See the Docs about it.

Comment: @Jimi Im just exploring C# and how its different to Java.  I did end up using SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, filepath, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);